# Searching for an ID in a list of books

Tags: python, oop

I've made a simple library system which stores books with an ID, name and cost. My question is rather simple but my limited knowledge of python has let me down.

I've created a class that stores books in the library, they are created like this;

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib = Library()
    book1 = Book(1, 'Bookname1', "$30")
    book2 = Book(2, 'Bookname2', "$10")
    book3 = Book(3, 'Bookname3', "$40")
```

I have to make a function that searches for a book by its ID, by making a function in my library class. I tried to make it like in the code below, but it didn't work. basically, I want to give my function an ID, and it should return the name and cost of that particular book, but only if the ID is present in the list.

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, ID, name, price):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def show(self):
        print(self.ID, self.name, self.price)

    def get_attribute_string(self):
        print(str(self.ID) + '_' + str(self.name) + '_' + str(self.price))

    def get_id(self):
        print(self.ID)

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def get_price(self):
        print(self.price)


class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def add_book(self, Book):
        self.books.append(Book)

    def remove_book(self, Book):
        self.books.remove(Book)

    #def show_id(self, ID):
    #    if ID in lib:
    #        return self.books

    def show_all(self):
        for Book in self.books:
            Book.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib = Library()
    book1 = Book(1, 'Bookname1', "$30")
    book2 = Book(2, 'Bookname2', "$10")
    book3 = Book(3, 'Bookname3', "$40")
    #1.show_id
    lib.add_book(book1)
    lib.add_book(book2)
    lib.add_book(book3)
    lib.remove_book(book2)
    lib.show_all()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest idea if you need `ID` indexing is to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries):

```py
class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = dict()

    def add_book(self, Book):
        self.books[Book.ID] = Book

    def remove_book(self, Book):
        del self.books[Book.ID]

    def get_book(self, ID):
        return self.books[ID]

    def show_id(self, ID):
        self.get_book(ID).show()

    def show_all(self):
        for Book in self.books.values():
            Book.show()
```

You could even rename `get_book` to [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), this second name is special in python, it's called a dunder method (or magic method). Implementing it will allow you to write `lib[id]` instead of `lib.show_id(id)` (I'm not saying that you should, but that's an option). There are many other dunder methods that you can try using for fun, you can find some of them in the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

I think that you should post your code on [**codereview**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as you may use broader advices on your code.

Comment: Dang you beat me to it! If I remember correctly you had it as a list originally so I started writing this then you edited haha nice though!

Comment: nice one, nitpick that OP wanted to return `return the name and cost of that particular book`, not the entire book object, e.g. by returning list or tuple.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think (giving the name of the method) that the goal was to call `.show()` on a given book using its `ID`, let me know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

As  noted above, there might be better implementations, but using your current code, you can do the below where I have adapted your `show_id` function according to requirements. It relies on a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) to identify the correct IDs.

Hope this helps!

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, ID, name, price):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def show(self):
        print(self.ID, self.name, self.price)

    def get_attribute_string(self):
        print(str(self.ID) + '_' + str(self.name) + '_' + str(self.price))

    def get_id(self):
        print(self.ID)

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def get_price(self):
        print(self.price)


class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def add_book(self, Book):
        self.books.append(Book)

    def remove_book(self, Book):
        self.books.remove(Book)

    def show_id(self, ID):
        # simple list comprehension to filter; note that you might need to make sure that e.g. all IDs are int, or str
        matching_ids = [book for book in self.books if book.ID == ID]
        # return name, price tuple for all matching books as requested -- note that this will return a list of all matches
        # if the IDs are truly unique, you can return e.g. a single tuple or Book object here
        # if nothing found, will return empty list
        return [(book.name, book.price) for book in matching_ids]


    def show_all(self):
        for Book in self.books:
            Book.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib = Library()
    book1 = Book(1, 'Bookname1', "$30")
    book2 = Book(2, 'Bookname2', "$10")
    book3 = Book(3, 'Bookname3', "$40")
    #1.show_id
    lib.add_book(book1)
    lib.add_book(book2)
    lib.add_book(book3)
    lib.remove_book(book2)
    lib.show_all()
    print(lib.show_id(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if this method is not really optimized, you can go through them with a for loop.

```
for book in lib.books:
    if book.id == searched_id:
        searched_book = book
        break
```